# Null Pointer Exception in netflix hystrix library

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hystrix, netflix

Recently I started working on netflix hystrix library. I created a HystrixCommand object but I get a NPE. Ideally, it shouldn't happen. Any help will be appreciated. Is it a known issue ?

Please find the stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.netflix.config.ConcurrentMapConfiguration.clearConfigurationListeners(ConcurrentMapConfiguration.java:330)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.event.EventSource.<init>(EventSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:63)
    at com.netflix.config.ConcurrentMapConfiguration.<init>(ConcurrentMapConfiguration.java:68)
    at com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration.<init>(ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration.java:172)
    at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:125)
    at com.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance(DynamicPropertyFactory.java:263)
    at com.netflix.config.DynamicProperty.getInstance(DynamicProperty.java:245)
    at com.netflix.config.PropertyWrapper.<init>(PropertyWrapper.java:58)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.archaius.HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius$ArchaiusDynamicProperty.<init>(HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.java:62)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.archaius.HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius$StringDynamicProperty.<init>(HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.java:73)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.archaius.HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.getString(HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.java:34)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.getPluginImplementationViaProperties(HystrixPlugins.java:344)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.getPluginImplementation(HystrixPlugins.java:334)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.getPropertiesStrategy(HystrixPlugins.java:243)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.HystrixPropertiesFactory.getCommandProperties(HystrixPropertiesFactory.java:62)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.initCommandProperties(AbstractCommand.java:204)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.<init>(AbstractCommand.java:163)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.<init>(HystrixCommand.java:61)
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue, and here is how I solved it.

Hystrix -> uses archaius-core-0.4.1.jar -> which uses commons-configuration-1.8.jar

But due to jar conflicts in my current project, commons-configuration-1.3.jar is present instead of commons-configuration-1.8.jar

Unfortunately, there seems to be a **bug in commons-configuration-1.3.jar** in the constructor of org.apache.commons.configuration.event.EventSource (which I will explain below)

So, my suggestion is take a look into your classpath and I am sure you will find commons-configuration-1.3.jar. If so, just make sure you have the correct **commons-configuration-1.8.jar**. This should solve your problem!

**Root Cause:**

com.netflix.config.ConcurrentMapConfiguration -> is a sub class of 
org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration -> which is a sub class of org.apache.commons.configuration.event.EventSource

Here is the skeleton

```
public class ConcurrentMapConfiguration extends AbstractConfiguration {
   ...
   private Collection<ConfigurationListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<ConfigurationListener>();    
   ...
   public ConcurrentMapConfiguration() {
      ...
   }
   ...
   @Override
   public void clearConfigurationListeners() {
       listeners.clear();  // Here is the null pointer exception
   }
   ...
}
```

But in EventSource (commons-configuration-1.3.jar)

```
public class EventSource {
   ...
   public EventSource()
   {
       clearConfigurationListeners(); // This is the culprit
   }
   ...
   public void clearConfigurationListeners()
   {
       listeners = new LinkedList();
   }
   ...
}
```

As you clearly see in the constructor of EventSource, you see an invocation to method clearConfigurationListeners(). And this method has been overriden in subclass ConcurrentMapConfiguration. So, the subclass method will be invoked. But by this time listeners is still null, because only after super class constructor is done the subclass can start initializing its stuff. Hence the NPE.

But in EventSource (commons-configuration-1.4.jar and above) - it is fixed

```
public class EventSource {
   ...
   public EventSource()
   {
       initListeners(); // this is good
   }
   ...
   private void initListeners() // private method... Much better! No one can override this :)
   {
       listeners = new LinkedList();
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps!